# Define default Foundation grid in Rails that will pull columns

Tags: ruby-on-rails, layout, zurb-foundation

What is the best way to define a default grid using Foundation and Rails that will check the number of items in a row and pull columns to maintain the grid layout?

For example, I want a default layout that is 3 x 3 equaling 9 items in total I might do something like this:

```
<% @jobs.in_groups_of(3, false) do |row| %>
  <div class="row"> 
    <% for job in row %>
      <div class="large-4 columns>
        <div class="panel">
          <% job.address %>
          <% job.state %>
          <% job.postcode %>
        </div> 
      </div>
    <% end %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

If I have exactly 9 items my view would render like this:

```
   <div class="row"> 
      <div class="large-4 columns>
        <div class="panel">
          219/32 Makenzie Island Squares
          SCHUPPEMOUTH, MASSACHUSETTS
          44753
        </div> 
      </div>

      <div class="large-4 columns>
        <div class="panel">
          219/32 Makenzie Island Squares
          SCHUPPEMOUTH, MASSACHUSETTS
          44753
        </div> 
      </div>

      <div class="large-4 columns>
        <div class="panel">
          219/32 Makenzie Island Squares
          SCHUPPEMOUTH, MASSACHUSETTS
          44753
        </div> 
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row"> 
      <div class="large-4 columns>
        <div class="panel">
          219/32 Makenzie Island Squares
          SCHUPPEMOUTH, MASSACHUSETTS
          44753
        </div> 
      </div>

      <div class="large-4 columns>
        <div class="panel">
          219/32 Makenzie Island Squares
          SCHUPPEMOUTH, MASSACHUSETTS
          44753
        </div> 
      </div>

      <div class="large-4 columns>
        <div class="panel">
          219/32 Makenzie Island Squares
          SCHUPPEMOUTH, MASSACHUSETTS
          44753
        </div> 
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row"> 
      <div class="large-4 columns>
        <div class="panel">
          219/32 Makenzie Island Squares
          SCHUPPEMOUTH, MASSACHUSETTS
          44753
        </div> 
      </div>

      <div class="large-4 columns>
        <div class="panel">
          219/32 Makenzie Island Squares
          SCHUPPEMOUTH, MASSACHUSETTS
          44753
        </div> 
      </div>

      <div class="large-4 columns>
        <div class="panel">
          219/32 Makenzie Island Squares
          SCHUPPEMOUTH, MASSACHUSETTS
          44753
        </div> 
      </div>
    </div>
```

What usually happens though is that instead of 9 items you end up with 7 or 8 which means that you have to start adding the pull class to the last item - something like this:

```
    <div class="row"> 
      <div class="large-4 columns>
        <div class="panel">
          219/32 Makenzie Island Squares
          SCHUPPEMOUTH, MASSACHUSETTS
          44753
        </div> 
      </div>

      <div class="large-4 pull-4 columns>
        <div class="panel">
          219/32 Makenzie Island Squares
          SCHUPPEMOUTH, MASSACHUSETTS
          44753
        </div> 
      </div>
    </div>
```

Or:

```
    <div class="row"> 
      <div class="large-4 pull-8 columns>
        <div class="panel">
          219/32 Makenzie Island Squares
          SCHUPPEMOUTH, MASSACHUSETTS
          44753
        </div> 
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading the [Foundation documentation](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/grid.html) more thoroughly you can add "end" when a row doesn't have a count that adds up to 12. This stops the default floating of an element to the right.  While this isn't a perfect solution in a Rails loop simply adding this to each column fixes the problem with no unexpected behaviour.

```
<% @jobs.in_groups_of(3, false) do |row| %>
  <div class="row"> 
    <% for job in row %>
      <div class="large-4 columns end>
        <div class="panel">
          <% job.address %>
          <% job.state %>
          <% job.postcode %>
        </div> 
      </div>
    <% end %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```